# How to debug code within Jquery closure?

Tags: javascript, debugging, workflow, closures

I'm trying to become a better javascript developer by making use of established design patterns, avoiding polluting the global namespace, etc.  While it's taking me some time to get used to the different style of coding, there are lots of good resources.

Where I'm really lagging is in my development practices.  I'm used to being able to open Firebug / IE or Chrome console and invoking line by line tests and method calls.  This doesn't seem possible with all design patterns (intentionally, I suppose).

How do serious JS developers debug code within closures, etc?

ie:

```
$(function() {
  ...
  [declare lots of vars, functions, page load actions, etc.]
  ...
}
```

Do I really have to insert [debug/break statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ee819093) all over the place and then make sure they get wrapped/cleaned up before deployment?

Comment: I'm confused - what's wrong with break points? It doesn't modify your code, it remains clean for deployment.

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with it, but it's different.  Outside of a closure I can invoke any function at any time.  Working with breakpoints I have to add them in the places where I predict problems might occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var closure = (function(){function foo{...} return {'bar':foo}}());
```

now you can call something like `closure.bar()` ... and see what the result is

so long as you return an object that allows you to access the closure functions and vars you can test away...

**sometimes I will write my inital code without closure**

and make it all work... **then wrap it in a namespace** so I dont have to worry about it... but that is another approach

*it really depends on your code style and how you develop*

**test early test often**

best of luck

Comment: I tried this.  I think when the closure is wrapped in the Jquery onReady ($()) then Jquery returns the whole document.

Comment: Some of the code I've wrapped requires the DOM/Jquery to be ready.  Should this live outside the closure? Or live inside the closure with it's own $() jquery wrapper?

Comment: use $().ready(function(){init()}) .... or something like this where init sets up your namespaces